Lifetime of rvalue of custom class bound by rvalue reference
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Someclass
{
    public:
    
    ~Someclass()
    {
        cout << "Someclass Dtor called" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Someclass obj;
    
    {
        Someclass&& ref = move(obj);
    }

    // At this point why the dtor is not called ? Because the reference went out of scope
    
    cout << "Ending program" << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

In the above code the output is as follows:
Ending program
Someclass Dtor called
But my query is why the output is not this ?
Someclass Dtor called
Ending program
When the reference is going out of scope, should it not invoke dtor of Someclass?


why the output is not this ?

Because no move operation(move construction/assignment) happens. in your example since ref is an rvalue reference. Basically, std::move(obj) just gives an xvalue which is then bound to the rvalue ref ref.
ref is still just an alias for the  actual object obj whose lifetime only ends after the } of the main.

If you were to remove the && from ref, then you would observe your expected output because in this case move operation does happen:
{
//-----------vv----------------> && removed from here
    Someclass ref = move(obj);
}

The output of the above modified program will be:
Someclass Dtor called
Ending program
Someclass Dtor called

Demo

But in this case, assume I have a move ctor defined with proper move semantics, I would expect the original obj be destroyed after move is done. Because ownership is now transferred to ref. Just as if I had a vector list. And I would I insert a object in it like list.push_back(Someclass())
How to achieve the same behaviour here?

std::move() is basically a cast to && but not a call to the destructor. Whether the move semantics happens or not depends on the left hand side as well as this contributes to which constructor (in declaration / initialization) or assignment operator (in expression) is used. So, it depends on their implementation (even if it is provided by the compiler). I wouldn't expect that any of them calls the destructor except (maybe) for a temporary e.g. created by an implicit conversion or if the copy/swap idiom is used internally...

I am not able to understand, who calls the dtor in case of vector I mentioned above.
Is it he rvalue reference itself calling the dtor because it goes out of scope just after the move ctor call completes? (Assuming that the reference is binded to temp and owns it)

@Avi destruction of the xvalue (the temporal), obviously.

@Avi You're missing the point which is that even if you implement move ctor with proper move semantics, the move ctor won't be used because you're  creating an alias using Someclass &&ref=move(obj); instead of creating an actual object like Someclass obj=move(obj);. See demo where I've added move and copy ctor and you'll see that neither of them is called/used for Someclass&& ref = move(obj);. This is because as I explained in my answer, you're creating a rvalue ref. If you replace it with Someclass ref = move(obj);, you'll see the move ctor called.


When the reference is going out of scope, should it not invoke dtor of Someclass?

No. A reference is an alias, or an alternative name, for an existing object. It provides a way to access an object by another name. It doesn't own the object in your case.
Therefore when this line:
{
    Someclass&& ref = move(obj);
}

rvalue ref goes out of scope, the only alias is going out, not the actual object.
The actual object obj goes out of the scope at the end of main(). Hence the result.

However, (as @HolyBlackCat mentioned) reference can own an object that had its lifetime extended.
In the following, the temporaries get an extended lifetime while passing to the functions with given references, and they own the temporary object as well.
void foo(const Someclass&) {}
void boo(Someclass&&) {}
void bar(const Someclass&&) {}

foo(Someclass{});
boo(Someclass{});
bar(Someclass{});


This is correct in OP's case, but a reference can own an object that had its lifetime extended.

In function parameters the references don't really do any lifetime extension, because the temporary would live until the end of the full expression regardless. It does happen e.g. with standalone variables: const Someclass &ref = Someclass{};.

So you mean in my case, the reference is not binded to a temporary? Hence does not own it.
Means rvalue can have 2 meanings. It can either be a temporary or non temporary?
What really happens in case of Move ctor with proper move semantics. We do set the original object to null

You have a slightly incorrect understanding of the concepts of moving, references, and object lifetime.

Moving does not affect lvalue lifetime (moving only takes away the object's contents).
The lifetime of an lvalue is determined by its scope.
Those in your example, the obj destructor will always be called at the end of the function main(),
even if you do a real moving of obj:
 int main()
 {
     Someclass obj;
     Someclass obj1(std::move(obj));
     cout << "Ending program" << endl;
     return 0;
 }


When a reference goes out of scope, the object's destructor is not called.
In general, the expression
 Someclass&& ref = move(obj1);



is actually useless - the ref variable is an lvalue,
and therefore it cannot be used to moving directly -
when the code
    Someclass&& ref = move(obj1);
    Someclass obj2(ref);

is executed, copy constructor will be called.
